# In Rails Console. how to update a field for all records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

how can I update a table Notification.email to all true in console?

In console, I'd like to loop through all the records in the table and set email = true.

Ideas?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You're looking for `update_all`. [See doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class).

Beware, no callbacks are triggered this way.

Comment: Thanks, this is a much more efficient way to do this than looping through each element.

Comment: @Ryan it is much more efficient but the lack of callbacks makes it hard choice in my experience. One of the most common use-cases (other than cleaning data, etc in development) is mass enabling / disabling entities. Typically such a data update merits notifying your users which I typically do via callbacks ;)

Answer (score 38):

this should work

```
Notification.all.each do |n| n.update_attribute(:email, true); end
```

edit: made custom from bricker:

```
Notification.all.each { |n| n.update_attribute(:email, true) }
```

Comment: `Notification.all.each { |n| n.update_attribute(:email, true) }` - semi-colons don't belong in Ruby. ;)

Comment: `Notification.all.each { |n| n.update_attribute :email, true }`

Neither do extra parentheses. ;) (And you can use the `do ... end` form without a semicolon, too, because `end` is (almost) never ambiguous: `Notification.all.each do |n| n.update_attribute :email, true end` --but without syntax highlighting this is less readable.)

Comment: If you have more than one statement you have to use semi colons, I just got used to it that way.

Comment: Check user3767658's answer if your table has more than 1000 rows.

Comment: You basically do `n` queries (if there's one million rows, you're firing 1 million queries) when you can achieve this in just one.

Answer (score 14):

You can use:

```
Notification.update_all(email: true)
```

If you additionally have a condition while updating you should use:

```
Notification.find_each { |n| n.email = (n.id > 100) ? true : false }
```

Use `Something.all` is bad idea for huge db table.

Comment: @user3767658 I tried the conditional method but it doesn't seem to work for me `Datum.find_each { |n| n.percent_prob = (n.percent_prob == 8.0847) ? 38.0381 : n.percent_prob }` (i.e. if percent_prob equals 8.0847 change to 38.0381 otherwise keep it the same)

Answer (score 8):

```
Notification.update_all(email: true)
```

is the basic answer.

You don't have to "loop through" per se by writing your own block: you can let active record do the hard work for you - here is an example of where you have an array of ids and you want to update their emails (i basically took this example straight from one of my controllers):

```
@notifications = Notification.where(id: [1,2,3,4,5,6]).update_all(email: true)
```

Edit: folks watch out for sql injection do not include a `params[:notification_ids]` in your "where" method with a raw string, without escaping, or you will suffer sql injection attacks; or be safe and use a hash. If that doesn't make sense, please review the following: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection

Comment: your answer is very helpful. But what is the purpose of the duplicates in the where clause?

Comment: there is no purpose. it was simply an example equivalent to etc etc.